# Summernote - how to combine Emojis and Mentions?

Tags: emoji, summernote, mention

i have to say, that i have NULL knowledge about JS, so i looking at it like on other languages as CPP and PHP but dont know any of funtions in this language. So i need your help. How to combine Hint: Mentions and Emojis in one summernote window?

When i simply paste one after another the first one not working. When i combine it. The mentions starting look like [img]:name: instead of just The_Name

here the link, check it out, and pls tell me how to combine it! pls thx
https://summernote.org/examples/#multiple-editor

Answer (score 2):

You should use hint array:

```
hint: [{
          match: /:([\-+\w]+)$/,
          search: function (keyword, callback) {
            callback($.grep(emojis, function (item) {
              return item.indexOf(keyword)  === 0;
            }));
          },
          template: function (item) {
            var content = emojiUrls[item];
            return '<img src="' + content + '" width="20" /> :' + item + ':';
          },
          content: function (item) {
            var url = emojiUrls[item];
            if (url) {
              return $('<img />').attr('src', url).css('width', 20)[0];
            }
            return '';
          }
        },
        {
            mentions: ['jayden', 'sam', 'alvin', 'david'],
            match: /\B@(\w*)$/,
            search: function (keyword, callback) {
              callback($.grep(this.mentions, function (item) {
                return item.indexOf(keyword) == 0;
              }));
            },
            content: function (item) {
              return '@' + item;
            }    
          }]
```